# Spring Websockets: How to validate message and receive clients?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I have Spring WebSockets configured and working. Clients subscribe to a specific topic (e.g. `/topic/contract/contract_id`) and whenever there's a message for that contract/topic, they receive it.

The issue is that certain types of messages being sent to this topic are sensitive and should only be received by some clients, but not others. So I need to analyze a message that's being sent when it's being sent, the clients that are subscribed to receive it, and let it through for some clients but not for others. Is there a way to do this in Spring WebSockets?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using Pub/Sub pattern. I am no expert on Spring Web Sockets, but it sounds like a dilemma on a higher abstraction and not on the level of data transmission.

There are two things you can do:

- Either disallow specific clients to subscribe to the channel at the first place, but it sounds like some messages are sent through, some are not. Hence I'd recommend the second option:
- Maintain public (group like) and private channels.

In the first case just intercept the end point or service that is being called during subscription, and throw a Security exception or communicate somehow disallowed join.

In the second case, have a unique strong id for the channel name, that is known only to those who concerned, and they can listen to private messages.

I had experience with the second case and it worked perfectly, although we had no critical information as it was part of a game, so only one player can receive that message and not the group.